# PHP Include function

Tags: php, arrays, include

Hi I'm getting wrong values when i include a file and use array variable from include file into current file.(ie) I have an array in rate.php file. I included(rate.php) into my current file(Bankrate.php). I need to access an array($commodities_arr) in bankrate.php file. when i run alone rate.php file i can get the expect answer. But when i include into bankrate.php and use the $commodities_arr it's giving wrong answer. But it include without errors.

Here is my included file(rate.php)

```
 <?php 
    $commodities_arr = array();
    $result_set = "myquery";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) {
        $selling_rate = '';
        $buying_rate = '';
    if($row['com_sel_active']==1 || $row['com_buy_active']==1) {
if($row['com_type']==0){
.
.
.
$selling_rate = $selling_con * $row['com_weight'];
.
.
.
$buying_rate = $buying_rate * $row['com_weight'];
}
}
}
    .....
    .....
    ........
    for(...){
       $commodities_arr['buying_rate'][$row['com_id']] = (int)$buying_rate;
       $commodities_arr['selling_rate'][$row['com_id']] = (int)$selling_rate;
    }
    ?>
```

and my normal file look like(Bankrate.php)
    $commodities_arr = '';

```
$filename = "../rate.php";
require($filename);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($commodities_arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

when I print array inside the `rate.php` it display what I expect.
(i.e)

```
Array ( 
   [buying_rate] => Array ( [1] => 29625 [6] => 29625 ) 
   [selling_rate] => Array ( [1] => 33617 [6] => 33617 )
)
```

But when I display inside Bankrate.php its not displaying expected answer.

```
Array
(
    [buying_rate] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0
            [6] => 0
        )

    [selling_rate] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0
            [6] => 0
        )    
)
```

Comment: Missing some critical code. Your example isn't cutting it.

Comment: If $commodities_arr is initialized in bankrate.php ? Also change include("$filename"); with include($filename);

Comment: i had changed like include($filename); even i'm getting like wrong answer

Comment: Try require in place of include and check if it gives fatal error. may be the file in not included.

Comment: i had tried required also. Tat's not a issue. File getting include. So 1ly i can get the array like Array ( 
   [buying_rate] => Array ( [1] => 0 [6] => 0 ) 
   [selling_rate] => Array ( [1] => 0 [6] => 0 )
)

Comment: why not to try mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array

Comment: I also tried mysql_fetch_assoc. Even though it's getting wrong array value